# Java Socks5 implementation

Tags: java, http, sockets, protocols, socks

I need to add the Socks5 protocol to a finished HTTP client/server which uses non-blocking sockets with `Selector`. I was thinking of creating own classes with the following parents: `SocketChannel`, `SelectionKey`, `ServerSocketChannel` and of implementing Socks5 in these classes.

Is it possible to do it via proxy?